# How to get Keycloak realm and user attributes in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: keycloak, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

In Spring Boot with MVC it was possible to get information about Keycloak user realm and defined attributes through injected `Principal` in controller method, which was of type `KeycloakAuthenticationToken`, which provides this information.

But in Spring Cloud Gateway with dependencies

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
```

and security defined through

```
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        // Authenticate through configured OpenID Provider
        http.oauth2Login();
        ...
}
```

security works and I managed to retrieve Principal through a filter

```
.filter((exchange, chain) -> {

                            return exchange.getPrincipal().flatMap(p -> {
                                System.out.println("Pricnipal class: " + p.getClass());
                                OAuth2AuthenticationToken token = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) p;
                                System.out.println("Token: " + token.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId() + "|"
                                        + token.getPrincipal().getAttributes() + "|" + token.getDetails() + "|"+ token.getPrincipal().getClass());
                                System.out.println("Exchange Attr: " + exchange.getAttributes());
                                OidcUser oicdUser = (OidcUser)token.getPrincipal();
                                System.out.println("OicdUser: "+oicdUser.getClaims()+ "|" + oicdUser.getIdToken().getClaims()+"|"+oicdUser.getAttributes());
                                Authentication aut = (Authentication) p;
                                ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest().mutate().header("username1", p.getName())
                                        .header("roles1", aut.getAuthorities().toString()).build();
                                return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
                            });

                        })
```

But its type is `OAuth2AuthenticationToken`. And there is basic info in it about authenticated user, but no Keycloak realm or user attributes data defined through Keycloak admin console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it works. There is nothing wrong with posted code. I didn't set Keycloak Mappers properly, which is needed to add attributes to token.
With that configured, above method is enough to retrieve user attributes from the token. 
They will be in `token.getPrincipal().getAttributes()` property of `OAuth2AuthenticationToken token`.

Comment: Hi @Vuk Djapic: I have been trying similar kind of thing where I am getting the OAuth2AuthenticationToken in my request. But I am having an issue that the token I am getting does not match the token I am getting from the keylcoak token endpoint. Is there any way I can get the OIDC token instead of OAuth2 token? I have added all the details in my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63020779/getting-access-token-with-spring-cloud-gateway-and-spring-security-with-keycloak